# warning C4020: 'CreateVertex' : too many actual parameters

Tags: visual-c++

What does that warning says?
I could not find any typos or extra characters in the code.:

```
if (!(connectedComp = (Vertex**)malloc(sizeof(Vertex*)))) {
    AllocationError();
}
if (!(created = (unsigned int*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int)))) {
    AllocationError();
}

connectedComp[++counter] = CreateVertex(id, edgesMatrix, maxValue, created);
```

I declared

```
Vertex** connectedComp = NULL;
```

and the function signature is:

```
Vertex* CreateVertex(unsigned int id, unsigned int** edgesMatrix, unsigned int maxValue);
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Function prototype of `CreateVertex` has 3 arguments and you are trying to send 4. That is the warning

Answer (score 0):

Well your function signature is

```
Vertex* CreateVertex(unsigned int id, unsigned int** edgesMatrix, unsigned int maxValue);
```

And you are passing 4 arguments. This is the problem and hence compiler is giving the following **compilation error**.

```
connectedComp[++counter] = CreateVertex(id, edgesMatrix, maxValue, created);
```

By looking your code your call should be

connectedComp[++counter] = CreateVertex(id, edgesMatrix, maxValue);

BTW, you should avoid using malloc/free in C++ instead of that use new/delete or smart_pointer mechanism.